# In C++, sizeof(array) is giving number of elements in the array, instead of (number-of-elements * size-of-each-element)

Tags: c++, arrays

The code in question is:

```
int* array = new int;
int array2[] = {2,3,4,5,6};
int noOfEl, i;
cin>> noOfEl;
for(i=0; i<noOfEl; i++)
   cin>> array[i];
cout<< "SizeOfArray-> " << sizeof(array) << endl;
cout<< "SizeOfOneEl-> " << sizeof(array[0]) << endl;
cout<< "SizeOfArray2-> " << sizeof(array2);
```

The input file is ***input.in*** which looks like:

```
4
8
2
17
9
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
SizeOfArray-> 4
SizeOfOneEl-> 4
SizeOfArray2-> 20
```

Why?

Shouldn't it be 20 in case of array as well?

Comment: array is just one integer.

Comment: Here's a clue: if you compile and run this on a 64-bit machine, the first line will print `8`. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) in its entirety.

Comment: `array` is not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: @n.m.But as is array2.

Comment: @HindK, No, `array2` is an [array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c). You also can't expect `noOfEl` to be greater than 1 and have your program exhibit any kind of normal behaviour.

Comment: BTW, you write out of bound of `array`

Comment: Can you tell `*` from `[]`? If it has a `*` it's a pointer. If it has a `[]` it's an array. Well, not always, just most of the time, but you should use neither arrays nor pointers anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Praetorian may be a bit quib but his link is good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c I think you would benifit from that high quality post

Comment: As @Jarod42 said, your code makes _undefined behavior_ by writing out of bound of `array` in `for` loop in your code, when program reads number greater than 1 from _stdin_ in line `cin>> noOfEl`. To fix it, you have to change the `for` loop, or the `array`'s size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is expected:

- `array` is a pointer to an `int`, so `sizeof(array)` returns the size of a pointer on your implementation.
- `array[0]` is an `int`, so `sizeof(array[0])` returns the size of an `int` on your implementation.
- `array2` **is** an array : `sizeof(array2)` returns the total size of the array (`N * sizeof(int)`)

Answer (score 2):

- `sizeof(array)` == `sizeof (int*)`
- `sizeof(array[0])` == `sizeof (int)`
- `sizeof(array2)` == `sizeof(int[5])` == `5 * sizeof (int)`